# How do I configure git to use a proxy

Tags: git

There is a http proxy on my school, and I nees to use git there, how can I bypass git traffic through HTTP proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider something like:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxy.server.com:port
```

It worked for me.